# Import Google sheet data directly into R

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api

Is it possible to import a table into R directly from Google docs without authorization key? I have a sharable google sheet that I try to connect to shiny app but couldn't find a proper way.

Comment: Haven't used it but apparently there is a `googlesheets` package....

Comment: The googlesheets package is great.  You can directly read from AND write to your gsheets from R, avoiding the need for an intermediate .csv or other file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the package `gsheet` you can read in a sheet from the shareable link.
Example given in the docs:

```
library(gsheet)
url <- 'docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I9mJsS5QnXF2TNNntTy-HrcdHmIF9wJ8ONYvEJTXSNo'
a <- gsheet2tbl(url)
```

It's quite nice.

Comment: Seems like this one can only download the first tab of the google sheet. The sheetid  have to effect when downloading.